# Subtype SwingWorker: where would I place my statements that would not run in the GUI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I have created a subtype of SwingWorker and I wanted to know where would I place my statements that would not run in the GUI thread.

Note: this is a simple SwingWoker subtype and it consists of `done() dolnBackground(), run(), process(), publish()`

(Don't know if I should have the run method in there)
Cheers

**UPDATE**

I just found out that I cannot call dolnBackground, process and done methods directly. I have a feeling the answer is the publish method. Can anyone please confirm.

Comment: stratwine has your answer. The publish/process pair are for when you want to display interim results from the doInBackground in your GUI. Again, you really must read the tutorial for SwingWorker.

Comment: Your question is not clear about what you want to achieve. Either you subclass SwingWorker "the usual way" and you want to put your long code in `doInBackground`. or you want to specialize SwingWorker in some way and then derive it further in your application; in this situation, you need to provide more information to get help.

Comment: feelings have their place, it's not here :-) No, it's not the publish method - read the tutorial, it'll help you understand which method is called when and how-to interact with the worker

Answer (score 8):

You could place the code in doInBackground() method.

And instead of directly invoking the method, you'd have to do something like

```
mySwingWorker.execute();
```

from the event-dispatch thread. That initiates the call.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am aware of the execute() although I want to know where to place my statements that would not run in the GUI thread out of the methods I have given.

Comment: @Jay there is answers to your questions, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html , btw your question is hard answerable

Comment: @Jay: stratwine has your answer (1+ to stratwine). You will want to read the tutorial that mKorbel links to, and then accept stratwine's answer.